# Using GSAP to Rotate Div Around Y-Axis at a Skewed Angle

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, gsap

I'm trying to make an animation of a book opening and closing using HTML, CSS, and GSAP. I have two problems:

1. The pages need to **rotate** into open and closed positions.
2. The z-index for one of the pages needs to change, and for some reason
   it's not.

[GIF animation of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ6Ks.gif)

[JS Fiddle showing current implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/1jy4np24/2/)


**HTML**

```
<div class="cover-info">
  <a id="main-toggle" href="#">
    <div class="book-container">
      <span class="book-page p1"></span>
      <span class="book-page p2"></span>
      <span class="book-page p3"></span>
      <span class="book-page p4"></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**JS (using JQuery)**

```
$(".cover-info").each(function(index, element) {
    var p1 = $(".book-container .p1");
    var p2 = $(".book-container .p2");
    var p3 = $(".book-container .p3");
    var p4 = $(".book-container .p4");
    var tl = new TimelineLite({paused:true}); 
    tl
      .to(p1, 0.25, {
        css: {
          rotationY: "180deg",
          transformOrigin:"0 100%",
        },
        ease: Power1.easeOut
      })
      .to(p2, 0.2, {
        css: {
          rotationY: "135deg",
          skewY: "30deg",
          transformOrigin:"0 100%",
        },
        ease: Power1.easeOut
      })
      .to(p3, 0.1, {
        css: {
          rotationY:"45deg",
          skewY: "-30deg", 
          z: "2",
          transformOrigin:"0 100%",
        },
        ease: Power1.easeOut
      });
    element.animation = tl;
  });
  $(".cover-info").hover(over, out);
  function over(){ this.animation.play() };
  function out(){ this.animation.reverse() };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out — apply the rotationY as a GSAP attribute, not CSS.

```
  $(".cover-info").each(function(index, element) {
    var p1 = $(".p1");
    var p2 = $(".p2");
    var p3 = $(".p3");
    var p4 = $(".p4");
    var tl = new TimelineLite({paused:true}); 

    tl
      .to(p1, .2, {
        rotationY: "180deg",
        css: {
          skewY: "-180deg",
          transformOrigin:"0 100%",
          zIndex: "2",
        },
        ease: Power1.easeOut,
      })
      .to(p2, .15, {
        rotationY: "135deg",
        css: {
          skewY: "-135deg",
          transformOrigin:"0 100%",
        },
        ease: Power1.easeOut,
      })
      .to(p3, .05, {
        rotationY:"45deg",
        css: {
          skewY: "-45deg", 
          transformOrigin:"0 100%",
        },
        ease: Power1.easeOut,
      });
    element.animation = tl;
  });
  $(".cover-info").hover(over, out);
  function over(){ this.animation.play() };
  function out(){ this.animation.reverse() };
};
```